# value of jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list, that each and one of them have a value.
I want to send to some input hidden the values after I sort them out

the sortable is working fine, but I cant get the value after (and before) the sortable thingy..

this is my code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="op" id="op" value="" />
<div class="wpr">
    <div class="wprCntnt">
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="1" value="1" >Item 1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="2" value="2" >Item 2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"id="3" value="3" >Item 3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"id="4" value="4" >Item 4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"id="5" value="5" >Item 5</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"id="6" value="6" >Item 6</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"id="7" value="7" >Item 7</li>
        </ul>
         <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="sayvalue()" />
    </div>       
</div>

$(function () {
    var op = $("#op");
    var lengthi = $(".ui-state-default").length;
    var valueSchtick = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < $(".ui-state-default").length; i++) {

        valueSchtick += op.val() + "," + $('.ui-state-default').eq(i).val();

        //        op.val(op.val() + ',' + $('.ui-state-default').attr('id'));
        //  op.val() = valueSchtick;
    }

    //   $("#op").val() = valueSchtick

    var sortableLinks = $("#sortable");
    sortableLinks.sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight1"
    });

    var linkOrderData = $($("#sortable")).sortable("serialize");

    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want to make? 1,2,3,4,5,6,7?

Comment: If I sort it as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 then yes.   but it could be also 7,1,2,3,4,5,6 for example

Comment: and you want to append `op.val()` to each value of `li`?

Comment: not to , but from :)   I want to select the values of each LI in that order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correct:

```
$(function () {
    var linkOrderData;
    var op = $("#op");
    var sortableLinks = $("#sortable");
    var setValues = function(){

        linkOrderData = sortableLinks.sortable("toArray");
        var values = new Array();
        $.each(linkOrderData, function(index, value){
            values.push($('#'+value).val());
        });
        values = values.toString();
        op.val(values);
    }

    sortableLinks.sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight1",
        update: function(event, ui) {
            setValues();
        }
    });


    setValues();
    sortableLinks.disableSelection();
});​
```

check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYgxE/1/)

Comment: Sorry, I've updated, it didn't take the value, it take the id, now it's correct